# Problem using LogisticRegression, polynmomialFeatures and pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm new to the machine learning area and I have a problem with my training code. When I run PolynomialFeatures to a degree greater than or equal to 2 the pipeline.fit runs out of ram. My question is whether I am doing something wrong with this code?

```
x = np.array(df_train[lista])  #x.shape: (2000, 529)
y = np.array(df_train["label"]) #y.shape: (2000,)

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)

clf = LogisticRegression(C = 0.01, max_iter = 4000, class_weight="balanced")

pipeline = Pipeline([("poly",poly),("scaler",scaler),("clf", clf)])

pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: What's your ram size?

Comment: I'm using google colab 25gb

Comment: Sometimes it takes more than 10 minutes running but at some point it runs out of ram